# Persistent storage with Ignite C++

Tags: c++, cassandra, ignite, persistent-storage

I'm new in Apache Ignite and was able to run persistence store with Cassandra using Java.
Is its possibly to do the same using Ignite C++?
If so how is the Cassandra column family object serialization done with C++ Class?

Comment: Did you check this https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/v1.9/docs/ignite-with-apache-cassandra

Comment: Yes, but not much on Ignite C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignite stores data in binary format [1] and the cache store works with binary object rather than with your classes. Therefore, there is no difference whether data was originated from Java, C++ or .NET. You can use persistence functionality without changes.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller

Comment: Thanks a lot. Persistence cache worked from my C++ code base. But i still need POJO for this. Is there any method to avoid POJO and do with C++ class?

Comment: Yes, for now Cassandra requires POJO classes if you use POJO strategy. You can save objects as BLOBs though, in these case classes are not required.

Comment: Is there any examples for Ignite C++ with Cassandra for persistence? Can anyone one add one to git. Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference between C++ and Java in terms of persistence configuration. If you use `BLOB` strategy, you don't even need Java classes. In case of `POJO` strategy, you will need to create POJO classes in Java that correspond to your data model classes in C++.

Comment: So how could we map Cassandra fields to ignite cache, i mean in ignite c++?

Comment: Cache internally still works in Java and doesn't even know that you're suing C++ :) So Cassandra configuration is provided in exactly the same way as described in the docs. The only additional requirement that exists now (and will be removed in the future BTW) is to create Java model classes that correspond to C++ model classes (ones that you want to save in Cassandra). Ignite's binary protocol supports interoperability by default, you can read here for example: https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/cross-platform-interoperability